# On click get ajax request 4 times

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

Get issues when i click one time i got 4 request on console. like this.
[image]

here is my code

```
var opener = listTreck.find('.row-holder');

opener.on('click.b touchstart.b', function() {

  refreshPosition();

  var self = jQuery(this);
  if (!self.parent().hasClass('active')) {
    openerParent.removeClass(activeClass);
    self.parent().addClass('active');
  } else if (self.parent().hasClass('active')) {
    openerParent.removeClass(activeClass);
  }

  if (!row.hasClass('details-open')) {
    colSlide.stop().animate({
      marginLeft: -slideWidth
    }, animeSpeed);
    trackDetails.stop().animate({
      marginLeft: -slideWidth
    }, animeSpeed, function() {
      row.addClass('details-open');
      resetStyle();
      colHidden.css({
        display: 'block',
        position: 'absolute',
        left: '0',
        marginLeft: -slideWidth
      });
    });
  }

  if (self.attr('data-src')) {
    var url = self.data('src');
    //var data = { _token: _globalObj._token };
    var data = {};

    if (isRoute('/favorites')) {
      data.f = true;
    }

    jQuery.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      data: data,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
        ajaxHolder.hide().text('');
        var html = jQuery('<div>').html(data);
        html.appendTo(ajaxHolder);
        ajaxHolder.fadeIn('normal', function() {
          scrollTrackInfo();
        });

      },
      error: function() {
        if (window.lonsole) {
          console.log('ajax Error');
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

when i click .. then i got issue on console request.why my ajax call 4 times. i got data properly on this code but only issue is... get many request.
when i click .. then i got issue on console request.why my ajax call 4 times. i got data properly on this code but only issue is... get many request.
when i click .. then i got issue on console request.why my ajax call 4 times. i got data properly on this code but only issue is... get many request.

```
'980..': {
            on: function() {
                initTrackInfo();
                jQuery('.side-menu').each(function(){
                    var set = jQuery(this);
                    set.find('.scrollable-area').each(function(){
                        if(this.jcf) this.jcf.destroy();
                    });
                    jcf.customForms.replaceAll(set.get(0));
                });
            },
```

Comment: You probably added the event handler multiple times.

Comment: Could you have added the event handler in a loop? You don't set `opener` to a specific element, it matches the whole class, so every time through the loop you're adding another listener to every element of the class.

Comment: no barmer.......

Comment: Are you creating elements dynamically and adding the event handler each time you create a new element? Use event delegation for dynamically-created elements.

Comment: @Barmar  i checked everything ... their are no loop for event.

Comment: Things like this don't happen by themselves. I suggest you put `console.log("adding handler")` before `opener.on` and see how many times it logs.

Comment: You can also put a debugger breakpoint there and see where it's being called from.

Comment: @Barmar  i chekked by console... nothing shown.

Comment: @Barmar when i refresh page... adding handler showing 2 times

Comment: Like I suggested above, use a debugger breakpoint to see where it's being called from.

Comment: @Barmar i got issue... but i cant delete this function

Comment: @Barmar checked now

Comment: What is that new code you added, and how does it relate to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    I added e.stopImmediatePropagation();   on 

    opener.on('click.b touchstart.b', function() {

        e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
    .........other Code........
  }
    It solved my issue.
```

Comment: Where did you add it? Also please [edit] the question so that only the code is formatted as such.